# c# GMT time equivalent with UTC time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can I get the GMT time in .net(c#) ... is the UTC time equivalent to the GMT time?

Thanks, Radu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Universal Time, "Zulu time", and UTC are effectively modern names for Greenwich Mean Time.

Comment: moder names? Not exactly. GMT is a time zone while UTC is a time standard (not a time zone!). No country officially use UTC as a local time. They just two different things - but the "time" is the same for both - that is correct.

Comment: GMT was a time standard before it was a time zone (George Airy and all that)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the UTC time is (for all intents and purposes) equivalent to the GMT time. You can use the [`DateTime.ToUniversalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) method to get the UTC time. For example, to get the current UTC time:

`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: Or, more directly, with `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Answer (score 7):

"GMT" is ambiguous, you need to avoid the term.  It could represent the time kept by the Royal Observatory in Greenwich, that matches UTC.  Or it could match the name of the timezone for London.  Where daylight savings time is observed, it only matches UTC in the winter.

Comment: Having grown up in the UK, the term 'GMT' is only used for UTC and 'winter time'. Daylight savings uses BST or British Summer Time which is 1hr ahead of GMT. I have never heard of BST being referred to as GMT. The general public know the difference.

Comment: It is the name of the timezone in Windows, "GMT Standard Time".  The Display name does not win prizes either: "(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London".

Answer (score 2):

GMT is the same time as UTC, but it is a different timezone so theoretically they could be different (though that is highly unlikely).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> Though there are scientific differences (explained below) between "Coordinated Universal Time" and the time standard known as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) - in the very broadest sense as understood by non-scientists, "Coordinated Universal Time" in essence is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). When times are listed as being "UTC" - this is de facto the equivalent of "GMT".

Answer (score 1):

use

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
```

Comment: This is the same as the first posted answer and doesn't add any new information.